# How can i solve Was not declared problem in my code?

Tags: c++

```
Hello i am a newbie on C++. I tried to run my first Class code but it didn't work it what is my problem please help me.



#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Car
{
public:
string brand;
string model;
int year;
};




 int main()
 {
    Car carobj1;
    carobj1.brand = Ford;
    carobj1.model = Mustang;
    carobj1.year = 1969;

    Car carobj2;
    carobj2.brand = Tofas;
    carobj2.model = Sahin;
    carobj2.year = 1998;

    cout << carobj1.brand << "  " << carobj1.model << "   " << carobj1.year << "\n";
    cout << carobj2.brand << "  " << carobj2.model << "   " << carobj2.year << "\n";
    return 0;

 }
```

||=== Build: Debug in Deneme (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Deneme\main.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Deneme\main.cpp|21|error: 'Ford' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Deneme\main.cpp|21|note: suggested alternative: 'void'|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Deneme\main.cpp|22|error: 'Mustang' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Deneme\main.cpp|26|error: 'Tofas' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Deneme\main.cpp|27|error: 'Sahin' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Users\azman\OneDrive\Masaüstü\Deneme\main.cpp|27|note: suggested alternative: 'main'|
||=== Build failed: 4 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put your model names and brand names in quotes, so the compiler does not understand that these are strings.

```
Car carobj1;
carobj1.brand = "Ford";
carobj1.model = "Mustang";
carobj1.year = 1969;
```

Remember, in C++ all text must be surrounded by " otherwise the compiler will think it is a name of something (class, function or variable) and will look for it in your code!